# Similarity in triangles

Tags: geometry

Sides $AB$ and $AC$ and median $AD$ of a $\triangle ABC$ are respectively proportional to sides $PQ$ and $PR$  and median $PM$ of another $\triangle PQR$. Show that $\triangle ABC$ is similar to $\triangle PQR$.

I don't know how to start this.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

- Consider the picture below

[image]

- Let $|AQ'| = |PQ|$ and let the line $k$ be parallel to $BC$, $k \parallel BC$.
- Set $M'$ to be the intersection of $k$ and $AD$ and $R'$ to be the intersection of $k$ and $AC$.
- By the [intercept theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem) we have that $|AM'| = |PM|$ and $|AR'| = |PR|$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$